# how to play non-stop audio files in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a react app that plays songs fetched from ftp server. first song plays without any problem but next song won't play. how can i play multiple songs without reloading page in react js? here is my player component:

the main concet is that when `location` state changed next audio source should replace previous source and plays automatically

1. I have my radio state in context
2. `getTrackInMemory` function just simply returns a blob url of song
3. `getNextTrack` get upcoming song data and store it to radio state

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container } from '@mui/material'
import { useAxios } from './../hooks/useAxios'
import {
    getCoverUri,
    deleteTrackFromMemory,
    getTrackInMemory
} from './../utility/utility'
import Player from './../components/player'
import Background from './../components/background'
import { useRadio, useRadioUpdate, radioInitialState } from './../context/radio-context'

const Radio = (props) => {
    const [isAudioLoaded, setIsAudioLoaded] = useState(false)
    const [loadEvent, setLoadEvent] = useState(null)
    const [timeUpdateEvent, setTimeUpdateEvent] = useState(null)
    const [playsCount, setPlaysCount] = useState(0)
    const params = useParams()
    const location = useLocation()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const radio = useRadio()
    const radioUpdate = useRadioUpdate()
    const miniPlayer = useMiniPlayer()
    const miniPlayerUpdate = useMiniPlayerUpdate()
    const axios = useAxios()

    const getTrack = (cb, pc) => {
        let uri = 'tracks/random'

        if (params.id && params.id != 'undefined') {
            if (pc === 0) {
                uri = `tracks/stream/${params.id}`
            }
        } else if (radio.mood && radio.mood !== 'none') {
            uri += '?playlist=' + radio.mood
        }

        axios.get(uri)
            .then(async res => {
                cb(res.data.data)

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            }).finally(() => {

            })
    }

    const getNextTrack = (pc) => {
        getTrack(trackData => {
            radioUpdate(prev => {
                return {
                    ...prev,
                    upcoming_track_data: {
                        _id: trackData._id,
                        title: trackData.title,
                        artist: trackData.artist,
                        album: trackData.album,
                        cover: getCoverUri(trackData.cover)
                    },
                    show_upcoming: true,
                    execute_next: true,
                }
            })
            
        }, pc)
    }

    const timeUpdateHandler = (position) => {
        radio.track.currentTime = position
        radioUpdate(prev => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                track: radio.track,
                position
            }
        })
    }

    const playPauseHandler = () => {
        if (radio.play_status === 'playing') {
            radio.track.pause()
        } else {
            radio.track.play()
        }
        radioUpdate(prev => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                track: radio.track,
                play_status: prev.play_status === 'playing' ? 'paused' : 'playing'
            }
        })
    }

    const volumeChangeHandler = level => {
        localStorage.setItem('volume_level', level)
        radio.track.volume = level
        radioUpdate(prev => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                track: radio.track,
                volume_level: level
            }
        })
    }

    const endHandler = () => {
        setIsAudioLoaded(false)
        navigate('/radio/' + radio.upcoming_track_data._id)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('radio called', playsCount)
        let isNextFetched = false

        radioUpdate(prev => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                position: 0,
                duration: 0,
                upcoming_track_data: {},
                show_upcoming: false,
            }
        })

        getTrack(trackData => {
            getTrackInMemory(trackData.track, audio => {
                setPlaysCount(prev => prev += 1)
                
                const radioState = {
                    track_data: {
                        _id: trackData._id,
                        title: trackData.title,
                        artist: trackData.artist,
                        album: trackData.album,
                        cover: getCoverUri(trackData.cover)
                    }
                }

                const canplaythrough = audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => {
                    radioState.track = audio
                    radioState.duration = audio.duration
                    radioState.position = 0
                    
                    
                    radioUpdate(prev => {
                        return {
                            ...prev,
                            ...radioState
                        }
                    })
                    
                    setIsAudioLoaded(true)
                    setLoadEvent(canplaythrough)

                    if (playsCount > 0) {
                        audio.play()
                    }

                })

                const timeupdate = audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', ev => {
                    const position = Math.floor(ev.target.currentTime)

                    if (position > ev.target.duration * 0.6 && !isNextFetched) {
                        isNextFetched = true
                        getNextTrack()
                    }

                    radioUpdate(prev => {
                        return {
                            ...prev,
                            position: position
                        }
                    })
                })
                setTimeUpdateEvent(timeupdate)
            })


        }, playsCount)
        
        return () => {
            if (radio.track) {
                deleteTrackFromMemory(radio.track)
                radio.track.removeEventListener('canplaythrough', loadEvent)
                radio.track.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeUpdateEvent)

                radioUpdate(radioInitialState)
            }
        }
    }, [location])



    return (
        <>
            {location && <div className="flex-center" style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 72px)' }}>
                {isAudioLoaded && <Container className="radio-container">
                    <Player
                        onTimeUpdate={ timeUpdateHandler }
                        onPlayPause={ playPauseHandler }
                        onVolumeChange={ volumeChangeHandler }
                        onEnd={ endHandler } />
                </Container>}
            </div>}
        </>
    )
}

export default Radio
```